# Sphinx search crashes when there are no indexes

Tags: search, sphinx

I want a sphinx searchd to start up but there are no indexes populated as yet. I have a separate cron job that pulls data from a data source and then calls the indexer to generate the indexes.

So the first time searchd starts the cron job has not yet run, hence there are no indexes. And searchd fails with errors like:

FATAL: no valid indexes to serve

Is there any way to get around this? e.g. to start earchd even when there are no indexes and if someone searched against it during that time, it just returns no docids. Later when the cron job runs, the indexes will be populated and then searched can query those indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *if someone searched against it during that time, it just returns no docids.*

That would require an actual index to search againast.

Just create an empty index. Then when indexer runs, it recreates the index (with data this time) and notifies searchd - using --rotate switch.

Example of a way to produce a 'empty' index, as provided by @ctx: (Added Dec, 2014)

> ```
> source force {
>   type = xmlpipe2
>   xmlpipe_command = cat /tmp/test.xml
> }
> index force {
>   source = force
>   path = /path/to/sphinx/datadir/filename
>   charset_type=utf-8
> }
> ```
>
> `/tmp/test.xml`:
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <sphinx:docset>
>
> <sphinx:schema>
> <sphinx:field name="subject"/>
> </sphinx:schema>
>
> </sphinx:docset>
> ```
>
> `indexer force` and now searchd should be able to run.

Alternativly can use something like `sql_query = SELECT 1,''` but that does require connection to a real database server.

Comment: The same way you create a normal index, just with a datasource that has no data.

Comment: Added an actual config; this answer was useless without.